# Split a huge CSV in three random files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a huge CSV and I want to split it in 3 random files with almost* equal size.

*almost: the size cannot be divided by 3

I was thinking to create 3 blank lists, then in a for loop, I would randomly choose one number between `range(0,len(mycsv))` and append it in each list. Then, I will create a csv with the files from the first list and go on. But I think that this will be slow enough. Is there any build-in way or an easier than my own?

Comment: Does it matter if it's slow? Will you redo this frequently? Have you actually tried it and discovered a performance problem? How huge is "huge"? 1,000 rows? 1,000,000? 1,000,000,000? There's certainly no `random.split_file_into_n_parts(filename, n)`.

Comment: I will do it only once, but I prefer to discuss it here so I could learn through the whole procedure and next time I will not have to open a question. The file is about 100.000 rows with 11 columns.

Comment: Seems to me a bit like Stack Overflow is being treated as a code writing service rather than a tool for learning by some posters these days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each line of your csv, randomly insert this line in one of three blank csv files. For 100.000 lines, it should not take long.

```
import random

with open("mycsv.csv") as fr:
    with open("1.csv", "w") as f1, open("2.csv", "w") as f2, open("3.csv", "w") as f3:
        for line in fr:
            f = random.choice([f1, f2, f3])
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: You don't need `.readlines()` -- you can iterate over `fr` directly -- and you can use `random.choice`, eg. `f = random.choice([f1, f2, f3])`.